# Add files to 7-Zip archive by dragging then onto the .7z file?

Tags: windows, 7-zip, drag-and-drop, file-archiver

With WinZip, it's possible to drop a set of files onto a zip/zipx file, which results in the files being added or moved (depending on how you drop them, in the usual Windows manner) into the archive. With 7-Zip this seem not to be supported "out of the box".

But I suspect that it can be achieved with suitable shell commands in the registry for the .7z file extension. I just don't know how... Or perhaps by using a batch script, maybe in combo with shell command in the registry?

Any suggestions?